# Log4j2.xml :Rolling log Files but keeping all logs of old file?

Tags: xml, log4j2

I am using logj2.xml to creating two log files one is Rolling on daily based another one is month based but months based file Rolling after a month but keeping old file logs. I want new log file should keep new logs not all previous logs.

anyone have idea please help

thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I am having a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: Ravindra, maybe show an example of what files exist before rollover, and what files you _want_ to see after rollovers.

Comment: new logs file keeping all previous old file logs but I want new file should keep new logs not old suppose in a month file size is 10MB logs generated  after one month again 10MB logs generated now new logs file size is 20MB  it is keeping previous and new both logs and more thing current file is keeping all logs which generated from starting to still.

Comment: Ravindra - I don't mean to be rude but do you have someone with better English skills who can help you reword your question? We just can't understand what you are asking.